# How can I display a search form based on a selected value

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I have the following function for a custom search in WordPress:

```
function my_search_form( $form ) {
  $form = '
  <div class="custom-search-dropdown">
    <div class="select-wrapper">
      <select class="blog-store-select">
        <option value="blog">BLOG</option>
        <option value="store">STORE</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <form role="search" method="get" class="searchform" action="' . home_url( '/' ) . '" >
      <input type="text" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" class="s" placeholder="Site search" />
      <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" class="search-btn" value="'. esc_attr__( '&#xf002;' ) .'" />
    </form>
  </div>';

    return $form;
}
```

I have a select dropdown:

```
 <select class="blog-store-select">
  <option value="blog">BLOG</option>
  <option value="store">STORE</option>
</select>
```

What I am trying to do is either use the regular WP search if the `Blog` option is selected from the dropdown, or if `store` is selected, grab the value from the search and open a new window with the search parameter passed into a url that I will set.

I know I can get the select value using JavaScript with a  onChange function - but I am not sure how to handle this inside of php / WordPress. Any direction, or articles are very much appreciated.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Set the name of your select to `post_type`, then the value of the select must match the name of the post_type, for example: blog, the post type name is `post`.

Wordpress search query will interpret the `post_type` var and will only search on the given `post_type`,

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="searchform" action="' . home_url( '/' ) . '" >
      <input type="text" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" class="s" placeholder="Site search" />
      <select class="blog-store-select" name="post_type">
        <option value="post">BLOG</option>
        <option value="store">STORE</option>
      <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" class="search-btn" value="'. esc_attr__( '&#xf002;' ) .'" />
</select>
```